# UITableViewController, autolayout и tableHeaderView: заставить ресайзится под экран 3.5" автоматом

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, uitableview

Доброго всем времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой вот странной штуковиной:

При сборке `UITableViewController` в storyboard нет возможности добавить constraints в `tableHeaderView`:

[image]

отсюда проблемы на 3.5 экране: экран уменьшился и хотелось бы уменьшить tableHeaderView как раз на ту самую разницу, проблема решается очень просто в коде строчкой вида:

```
if (![UIScreen isiPhone5]) {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.width, mySmallScreenHeaderHeight);
}
```

но может кто-нибудь знает каким образом можно обойтись без изменения `tableHeaderView.frame` руками в коде, ведь autolayout, казалось бы, сильный и хороший инструмент и должен позволять настраивать такие элементарные и базовые вещи. Если у кого-то имеются соображения - смело делитесь, буду очень признателен за любую помощь!

Comment: А если добавить Bottom Space constraint между главной view и tableHeaderView? Тогда расстояние до низа будет всегда одинаковым и на маленьких экранах tableHeaderView придется сжиматься по высоте.

Answer (score 1):

Табличное хеадер и табл фоотер, так же как и селки не имеют реализации вызова super layoutSubviews метода который занимается пересчетом констрайнов,  это все связанно из-за убогости реализации UITableView, с одной стороны, и простоты производительности с другой. В связи с  этим данные вьюхи не поддерживают констрейнов. Одна из проблем которую не может решить UITableView это динамическое изменение contentSize свойства у ScrollView. Из за этого таблица запрашивает размер кажой ячейки перед тем как эту ячейку запросить на растеризацию и главное узнать полный размер для contentSize.
Данную проблему решить можно только перегрузкой всей таблицы с новыми фреймами. Так что это не проблема autolayout'ов это проблема UIView в реализации UItableView ^_^ вот такие пироги. Некоторые извращенцы не парятся с TableView а юзают CollectionView.

P.S. Автолайуты это не убицы фреймов, это дополнительный механизм созданый для облегчения решения большинства задачь, но не заменой фреймбилдингового подхода. И не бойтесь применять фреймы для одних вьюх и автолайауты для их сабвьюх. Это бест практикс. Это я в одной книжке прочитал )

Comment: ну да, похоже так и придется делать, насколько я помню раньше autoresizeMask решала эту проблему (хотя тоже довольно криво), а теперь только кодом.